# list of table which has the column in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

In my database, I have many tables which has the column StudentId, how can I get the list of the table which has this column in sql server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME='StudentId'
```

Comment: The JOIN isn't needed `SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME='StudentId' `

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to add that Red-Gate Software has an absolutely **free** tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) that is just absolutely wonderful to use and does this job with ease.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do a `SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'colname'` and then you can join that back to sys.tables on object_id. I dont have Sql Server on my pc now, but this should be very close.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.name 
FROM sys.table t INNER JOIN sys.column c
    ON c.objectid = t.objectid AND c.name LIKE 'studentid'
```